# variable accessibility during back grounding & sub processing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following two scripts:

"scr1.sh"

```
#!/bin/sh

func_in_scr1()
{

    echo func_in_scr1 var is $var


}

var=7645

func_in_scr1 &

( func_in_scr1 )

./scr2.sh
```

"scr2.sh"

```
echo in scr2 var is $var
```

Here is the output:

- func_in_scr1 var is 7645
- func_in_scr1 var is 7645
- in scr2 var is

Question:

1. When the function in scr1.sh is run in bg and in subshell it was able to access the value of $var.
2. However scr2.sh was not able to access the value of $var.

I was under the impression that a subprocess ( child process ) can only access exported variables and not un-exported variables , so I was specifically surprised by #1.

Can someone explain this result?

Comment: try adding `export var=7645`. Good luck.

Comment: I know, export will work. But I am trying to understand why the function started as a child process was able to access the variable but a new script started as a subprocess was not? This is not a problem to debug, but an example to help understand system behavior.

Comment: its all about scope. local vars are available to the current script, but not new scripts. Hence the need for export. A function, even inside a sub-shell is still scoped to the current script. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In these two cases:

```
func_in_scr1 &
( func_in_scr1 )
```

you start subshells. That is right that they are separate processes also but they see all variables of the parent shell (but of course you cannot give changes in this variables back; they are simple copies created during fork() of parent).

In this case

```
./scr2.sh
```

there is no subshell. You run a separate process. The parent shell knows nothing about it. Ant its has no other ability to give variables to him except exporting.